# match any number of consecutive words following a backslash

Tags: regex, matching, tex

I'm trying to match a TeX command, i.e. a backslash followed by a word (in a desired list) using regex, but with any number of them. For example, if the list I want is `test, other, list`, then the sequences `\test`, `\other`, and `\list` should be matched, while `\sdfsdf` should not. I also would want `\test\list` and `\test\other\list` to be matched. However, I don't want to match things like `\testagain` (although `\test again` should be). I tried the following regex

```
(\\)(test|other|list)([^a-z])
```

to no avail, since it does not match `\test\other`. How would I do this? I am not very experienced with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\b` to match the word boundary at the end of the word.

```
\\(test|other|list)\b
```